# The range of meromorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

Prove that:
if $f$ is a meromorphic function on $\mathbb{C}$, such that $\mathbb{C}_\infty-f(\mathbb C)$ has at least three points then $f$ is a constant.

I think that this should use transformations to take the function be entire, and then use Little Picard theorem, however I do not know how to do it.. 
any advice will be appreciated!

Comment: If $a,b,c$ are the points wlog assume none are infinity as otherwise done (function entire missing two points); then $\frac{1}{f-a}$ is entire and misses $\frac{1}{b-a}, \frac{1}{c-a}$ which are finite distinct values etc

Comment: @Conrad. Yes, you are right.  However, how to understand $\mathbb(C)_\infty$? If $"\infty"$ in one of these three points, does it still holds?

Comment: if infinity is one of those points, the function is entire (no poles as there you get infinity) and misses two finite values

Comment: @Conrad.  Yes, thank you very much!

Comment: happy to be of help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a bit less abstract:

Choosing well $a,b,c,d,ad-bc=1$ then  $g(z)=\frac{af(z)+b}{cf(z)+d}$ is entire and it misses $0$ and $1$.

Then $\lambda^{-1}(g(z))$ [is entire with image in the upper half-plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_lambda_function#Little_Picard_theorem) so that $\frac1{i+\lambda^{-1}(g(z))}$ is entire and bounded thus constant.

The difficulty is constructing $\lambda$, showing that $\lambda^{-1}$ is locally analytic on $\Bbb{C-\{0,1\}}$ and that it implies that (the correct branch of) $\lambda^{-1}(g(z))$ is entire.

Comment: ，thanks.  However, I think it is enough because the only possible kind of singularity point is pole.......

Comment: Not sure of what you mean, great Picard theorem is harder, yes.